# Local ubuntu 22.04 LTS server disappears at random from local network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh

I am quite the Ubuntu rookie, but here goes; I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server running on my local network. It's an old xeon server from about 10 years ago I bought cheap to have something to play with at home (Detailed hardware info here: https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/12617972).

The basic hardware setup is:

- IBM System x3650 M2
- Intel Xeon E5640
- 32 GB of RAM

After installing Ubuntu on the server it runs fine but after a while, seemingly at random (though usually after 10-15 minutes at most) my SSH session just stops responding and then the server disappears. I can no longer connect or ping to it when this happens. The server hardware is still running however I simply can't contact the server at all.

When this happens the powershell window writes the following:

`client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset`

If I reboot the server, then I can connect to it again and as before, some time passes and it disappears from my network yet again.

I am quite at a loss on what to do about this.

I use `openssh-server` server-side and I use `PowerShell` on a Windows 10 computer to connect to the server with the `ssh` command.

I am not running anything special on the server at all. I might simply completely reinstall the server from scratch soon to see if that fixes it, but before that I'd like to hear if anyone has any ideas on how to debug this?

EDIT 1:
These are the log entries server-side right before I lose connection:

```
9 04:23:51 server ModemManager[1047]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Oct  9 04:23:51 server NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1665289431.6707] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct  9 04:23:51 server NetworkManager[981]: <info>  [1665289431.6709] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Oct  9 04:23:51 server gnome-shell[1558]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Oct  9 04:23:51 server systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Oct  9 04:23:51 server systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Oct  9 04:23:51 server systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Oct  9 04:23:52 server systemd-sleep[4525]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Oct  9 04:23:52 server kernel: [ 1407.411612] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Oct  9 04:23:52 server systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct  9 04:23:52 server systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Oct  9 04:23:52 server systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
```

Comment: Might be hardware - In your shoes If its semi reliable, keep a ping running to see when it goes down, and check the logs around that time to see if something's failing. If its a NIC, should cost peanuts to replace

Comment: @JourneymanGeek how would I set up these logs or where would I possibly read them?

Comment: Well dmesg, /var/log/syslog and possibly systemd logs would be a where to look I think

Comment: @JourneymanGeek These are the last entries in the log, right before I lose connection: https://pastebin.com/YQ4bRF4S

Comment: Hmm. Looks like your server is sleeping - are you running a gui install ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am not. It should be a server version with no GUI to speak of. I only SSH into it. Now with that said, I have looked around a bit after seeing those log messages and I found that you can turn off the sleeping process. I would like to give you credit for leading me there though. By running the following, you break every process that could suspend your system due to inactivity
`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`
Can just as easily be undone with `unmask` instead.

Comment: Post how you found it and what you did  as an answer. I didn't do much more than point you very vaguely at a cause. This might be helpful for the next person with these issues

Comment: That said, I am seeing gnome shell and network manager - which are gui related. Ubuntu server won't do this

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Huh. That is strange. Maybe the guy I bought the server from didn't install a server image but just a desktop image? ._.
I did try and install a desktop environment once of sorts so that I could remote desktop onto the server with a GUI instead of purely SSH but that always crashed so I gave up. Could be remnants of that I left in.

Comment: Ah, I DID turn up something useful. If you do want to reinstall, its a good idea, and use the server image if you can.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek When I open my SSH session I see the following: `Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-48-generic x86_64)`. Should it be something else for it to be a server image?

Comment: I don't remember tbh, due to some quirks of my standard set up, I essentially run a minimal build from debbootstrap

Comment: I googled around and I am pretty sure it's a server image from what I've found. The answers say that if you see stuff like "System Load", "Usage of /:", "Memory Usage", "Swap usage", "Processes" and IP addresses upon ssh then it's a server image as the desktop version does not show all this informatiion.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Okay nevermind, another answer says running `dpkg -l network-manager` will let you know, because desktop uses Network-Manager and server doesn't. Mine does show a Network-Manager installed..so maybe ultimately this is a desktop version originally, but stripped of desktop packages??

That is confusing.

Comment: desktop certainly will run gnome shell, but server won't.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Okay sorry for the spam here. Turns out it *is* a server install. Someone pointed out that you can figure out what was installed by looking in `/var/log/installer` in the `media-info` file. If it says "server" in there, a server distro was at least what was originally installed on the system. Mine says:
`Ubuntu-Server 20.04.3 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Release amd64 (20210824)` which checks out as it was 20.04 originally and was upgraded to 22.04 a couple of days ago.